Problem using 'Fill' atributte in tailwind with NEXT.JS app
Im working on an Next App and adding styles with tailwind.The problem is that i have an Image with the atribute fill , envolved in a div with the positionrelative.Sometimes when I run my app locally, the browser doesn't care the position relative of the div father, and throws me this issue:
Image with src "/_next/static/media/pandereta.1025f212.jpeg" has "fill" and parent element with invalid "position". Provided "static" should be one of absolute,fixed,relative.
I found that is a problem of the Next version (14.2) but i dont know how to fix it, without having to update Next.
I tried adjusting the position manually when the application is running and it works, but how can I fix it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
